AMD/Xilinx SystemVerilog class variables dissapear in script vs. project simulaiton
I have asked this question on Stackoverflow but not answer yet. So, let me try EE stackexchange forum.
While scripting one of the SystemVerilog class-based testbenches I noticed that the testbench (code below) level variables are not visible in Vivado Objects tab. These variables are visible in the project based flow (please see two images).
class tb;

virtual my_bfm bfm;

tester     tester_h;
coverage   coverage_h;
scoreboard scoreboard_h;

function new (virtual my_bfm b);
  bfm = b;
endfunction : new

task execute();
  tester_h     = new(bfm);
  coverage_h   = new(bfm);
  scoreboard_h = new(bfm);

  fork
    coverage_h.execute();
    scoreboard_h.execute();
    tester_h.execute();
  join_none
endtask : execute

endclass : tb

Visible signals in project based flow:

Same signals disappear in scripted flow:


Recommend asking in the Xilinx/AMD support forums. Xilinx/AMD application engineers are there.  Its their job to support the parts and tools.

I don't think the Vivado Simulator gets a lot of use, especially the OO stuff. I have heard good things about it though.  The details of your issue are probably not widely known. From what you have shown in looks like a bug to me If you work for a company that uses a Xilinx then there should be an application engineer assigned to the company that can chase this for you.

I would be very surprised if this was not known to XILINX. Decades old problem with FPGA industry is that companies with 1000 FPGAs orders do have access to FAEs. Thus, their developer's questions get answered by them and not posted. However, for the rest of FPGA developers the questions never get answered.

In my experience, the solution for low volume customers has been distributor FAE's. They have the ability to elevate a case inside Xilinx if they can't solve it. I think the distributor guys have access to the inside corporate answer records.  I hope Xilinx does not hang small customers out to dry. Hobbyist and dev kit purchasers probably don't get much, which is not good because this crowd has the potential to become customers.
